# Wordpress admin cant create posts

Tags: wordpress

All of a sudden, this morning, both my wordpress sites wont let me post anything, but they do let me edit my older posts!

It just says 'Submit to review' where its supposed to say 'Publish', after which it tells me I have no permission to post. Although, I am the only admin. I also cannot create new admins.

Any ideas on that? Has anyone had a similar experience?

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: *"All of a sudden"* is quite worrisome, check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/19696/12615) and also do a full [troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list). First step is to disable all plugins and swap to a default theme (twenty10/11/12).

Comment: Are you still the only admin (according to wordpress) or has someone added themselves without your knowledge?

Comment: Thanks guys. Im the only admin. I think it might have to do with space for the database.. I'm trying to fix it